# php application suddenly slow on AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, latency

I'm running an old PHP (7.1) / NGINX (1.10.2) application on AWS. The application runs on AWS more than few months. Since 2 days we experiencing high latency issues. But it does not affect the whole page. Only "intensive" PHP processes seems to have problems deliver the content.

I looked up so many other related topics now but nothing was pointing me to the correct direction.

First of all: The latency is not related to networking as I get these latencies also when sending a request from the server to localhost. It doesnt seem to be related to the database as well (the website is able to connect to the RDS DB within <3ms and DB CPU ~20% and Memory free >2GB looks good). Connecting to the database and running some queries made by the webserver are also performing fine.

The Webserver itself doesnt consume so much hardware resources (CPU 10-25% and Memory free ~2GB). No cronjobs/scheduled tasks are installed on this server. More than 50% iNodes still available on the server. The network gateway is retrieving/transmitting 8-25MB/seconds. We do not monitor any kind of DoS at all.

I already checked and tried to adjust the PHP FPM settings (memory_limit, process management, children processes etc.) Nothing helped here. Deactiving/Activating OPCache doesnt really has an impact.

Even when I use an AMI from a previous installation and start a new server the same latency issue happens again. Same happens when running the application in multiple availability zones.

To see where PHP is spending time I used blackfire.io and actually its telling me it spends most of the time on mysql interactions (which is not surprisingly as the application sends a lot of dirty queries with a lot of joins etc. and its the only performance expensive thing here..). I also added some debug output to the code itself. It usually gets completed within less than 6 seconds (which is sadly the normal average we know from our search..)

The latency according to the target group is by average between 3-8 seconds but we also discover a lot of latencies where the request times out (30-60seconds).

At this point I'm even quite unsure about what to provide here. I don't want to paste every related config etc here. So please tell me what you need to be able to help here :/

php-fpm/nginx log doesn't log anything related to this issue. Same with the syslog. The only thing which can be found there is `Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com)` but even `date` is still in sync.. PHP FPM slow-log (timeout set to 5sec.) is empty as well. ELB Access logs are monitoring high "backend_processing_time"s only.

Nginx actually routes requests to an S3 bucket and besides one S3 mount we do not have any huge amount of temp files or other stuff on the server.

Requests send to the internet are performing as expected. DNS seems also not to be the problem (can reach db and other services in the internet as usual).

Does anyone has ideas what could cause these latency issues? What else should/**can** be investigated?? I really appreciate every help or question which can point me to the correct direction.
Best Regards.

Comment: Are you using T2 EC2 instances?

Comment: Yes usually small but I randomly also tried a medium ..

Comment: You need to set up some basic OS monitoring to keep an eye on things like CPU, memory, and IO so you have some visibility on what's happening on your servers. If your only visibility into performance is "the app is slow" you're going to have a real rough time figuring out what the problem actually is.

Comment: AWS provides you with that and the details are listed in my question

Comment: If you are using T2 instances then they could be running out of CPU credits. You need to check the CPU credit metrics for these instances in CloudWatch.

Comment: Average Credit Usage: 0.36 and average Credit Balance > 110. Looks like we have enough credits?

Comment: Ouuuh my .. Actually it is about RDS credit balance not EC2...

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself:

> its telling me it spends most of the time on mysql interactions (which is not surprisingly as the application sends a lot of dirty queries with a lot of joins etc. and its the only performance expensive thing here..).

It's your application. It's causing your "pipes" to clog so some people will experience that 30-60 wait. Now I would check also for any file_get_contents that are timing out now, since this was sudden.

Also, I had a problem like this [before on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/575451/nginx-php-fpm-each-php-fpm-process-70-100-cpu-when-running) and I specifically want to point out [my comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/575451/nginx-php-fpm-each-php-fpm-process-70-100-cpu-when-running#comment910314_575451):

> I don't work for that company anymore, and they went under - for legal reasons. But! When I left, our 30 second load site dropped to 3 seconds. and our linode CPU went down. the solution was entirely - caching. The initilization process of our framework was ridiculously expensive performance wise, and the in-house framework didn't have caching built in. All I can say is CACHE - object cache, page cache, use varnish! This will fix your problems (but you still will have a crappy framework and when you cannot cache, youll be sad.. youll have to fix the bad performing code).

I hope this helps you. Oh also [this comment too](https://serverfault.com/questions/575451/nginx-php-fpm-each-php-fpm-process-70-100-cpu-when-running#comment695533_575451):

> When you go to the doctor, and he tells you to take certain meds - because he knows you wont listen to the "stop drinking soda and eating fastfood" statements - this is exactly why there was no great answer for me - because the truth is, no setup or quick fix really applied - only the sad truth that we have to dramatically alter our web app itself.

Comment: Thanks for your hint regarding file_get_contents I'll look into that. Of course its obviously that it might be the app. But nothing changed between the last 3 days (no traffic increase, no index changes in the DB etc..) So I'd be really surprised if it just drops from 3-8 seconds to 30 or even 60 just because its a shitty legacy app..

Comment: Once we had that issue because of a file_get_contents on a sharing platform link. And of course we had an @ sign in front of it. Just a thought. Another is - are you being crawled? Heavier usage than you are used to (what a sentence!) could trigger the clog with a poorly designed app.

Comment: Try to figure out if that 30-60 seconds is exact, could coincide with actual timeout configurations. And on what urls / requests thats happening to.

Comment: Requests count and CPU usage on the servers stay constantly the same (including time before the latency started). The latency always differ and is on average even not that hight .. but still higher than usual + that >30s latencies. Its causing multiple sites with different content to work dramatically slower even the real execution doesnt take that long .. :( so its actually really hard to say

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR At Time of writing I wasnt really aware of the Fact that RDS has CPU Credits too**

A combination of robots, some stranger requests from cloud servers requesting only our search (since few months), RDS Cpu credits and by average really too many sql queries caused this phenomenon. Turned out that Cloudwatch Metrics for a t2 medium instance shows the average of CPU utilization (20%) for each of the 2 cores (baseline performance of t2.medium + sometimes higher values 30-80%) and this kills constantly all cpu credits once you lost them all and then it's really hard to earn new credits (e.g. during night).